# How can I measure the window height (number of lines) in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise, windows-console

The maximum number of lines in my environment is 47.

Can I measure this value programmatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To complement [Christian.K's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44871337/45375):

- A simpler and slightly more efficient method for obtaining the host object is to **use the `$Host` [automatic variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables)** rather than the `Get-Host` cmdlet.
- You're **only *guaranteed* to have access to window-size information** in the **PowerShell *console* host**, i.e., when **running in a *console (terminal) window***

  - It is at a given host's discretion whether to expose this information, and, as Christian states, **the PowerShell ISE does *not*** - even though it arguably *should*, given that it has a console subsystem *built in*.
- To **test whether your code is running in a *console* (a.k.a *terminal*)** or not, use
  **`$Host.UI.SupportsVirtualTerminal`** - `$True` indicates that the host is a console.

---

#### If running in the **PowerShell *console* host**:

You **can access the console's properties** either:

- via **`$Host.UI.RawUI`** (as in Christian's answer), which is an object of type `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostRawUserInterface]` that - *in the PowerShell console host only* - wraps the .NET `[Console]` class (see below).
- via the **[.NET `[Console]` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.Console.aspx)**; e.g., to get the window height (count of rows) this way, use:

  - `[Console]::WindowHeight`

Sample `$Host.UI.RawUI` output:

```bash
PS> $Host.UI.RawUI

ForegroundColor       : DarkYellow
BackgroundColor       : DarkMagenta
CursorPosition        : 0,58
WindowPosition        : 0,0
CursorSize            : 25
BufferSize            : 160,9999
WindowSize            : 160,75
MaxWindowSize         : 160,94
MaxPhysicalWindowSize : 303,94
KeyAvailable          : True
WindowTitle           : Windows PowerShell
```

---

#### If running in the **PowerShell ISE**:

<sup>Written as of PowerShell **version 5.1**</sup>

**Most of the properties in `$Host.UI.RawUI` are *not populated*** and will return their data type's default value:

```bash
PS> $Host.UI.RawUI  # in the ISE

ForegroundColor       : -1
BackgroundColor       : -1
CursorPosition        : 0,0
WindowPosition        : 
CursorSize            : 
BufferSize            : 166,0
WindowSize            : 
MaxWindowSize         : 
MaxPhysicalWindowSize : 
KeyAvailable          : 
WindowTitle           : Windows PowerShell ISE
```

The ***only* size-related information** that is available is the **buffer width** (`166` in the sample output above).

**There is *no* point in trying to use the .NET `[Console]` class in the ISE**, *except* to query / set the *character encoding* used for communication with external programs, `[Console]::OutputEncoding`:<sup>[1]</sup>

- *Initially* in a session, trying to use the window-related members of `[Console]` causes *exceptions*, because the ISE does *not* allocate a console window on startup:

  ```bash
  # In a pristine session.
  PS> [Console]::WindowHeight
  The handle is invalid.     # EXCEPTION
  ```
- While the ISE allocates a - hidden - console window *on demand*, namely the first time you run a *console application* in your session, that hidden console window's properties, as then reported on via `[Console]`, do *not* reflect the properties of the *simulated* console that the ISE presents to the user.

  ```bash
  # chcp is a console application, so when it is run, 
  # the ISE allocates a (hidden) console window, 
  # after which the [Console] API becomes technically usable, 
  # but DOESN'T REPORT MEANINGFUL VALUES.
  PS> chcp >$null; [Console]::WindowHeight
  72  # No exception, but the value is meaningless.
  ```

---

<sup>[1] Note that the ISE defaults to the system's legacy *ANSI* code page, whereas regular console windows default to the *OEM* code page. Thus, these two environments decode output from external programs differently by default.</sup>

Comment: Thank you, "[Console]::WindowHeight" it works well in powershell_ise.

Comment: @HyundongHwang: I'm glad to hear it, but it is surprising and contradicts my answer, so let's try to find out why: (a) When you paste `[Console]::WindowHeight` into the console pane in the ISE, you really get an integer value back (for me: the exception described above)? (b) What does `(Get-Command powershell_ise).Version.ToString()` report (for me: `10.0.15063.0`)? (c) What does `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()` report (for me: `5.1.15063.413`)?

Comment: Yes, it is different from your expectation.
I print a, b, and c values for debugging, and captured the screen. https://s23.postimg.org/y2kgpxpff/screenshot_2017_07_03_at_09_19_22.png

Comment: @HyundongHwang, mystery solved: Members such as `[Console]::WindowHeight` only start working _after you have run at least one external console application_ in a session, at which point a - hidden - console window is allocated. However, these members then report the properties of the _hidden_ console window, and these values have no meaningful relationship with the _simulated_ console that the ISE presents to the user. In short: Do not use `[Console]` in the ISE, except to query / set the _character encoding_ used for communication with external programs, `[Console]::OutputEncoding`

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like

```
$(Get-Host).UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Height
```

Note a couple of things however:

- Using the `RawUI` might not be particular "portable", depending on where your script runs. **In "ISE" for example, that property returns nothing**, while on the console it will work.

  For more difference here between the console and ISE, run `$(Get-Host).UI.RawUI` and compare the output.

  In other PowerShell hosts, besides the console or ISE, it might yet be still different.
- There is also a `BufferSize`, which can be bigger than the WindowSize. The later being only the part that is currently "viewable" by the user.

Your question sounds a little like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Consider explaining (as an edit to your question or a new question), what you're actually trying to achieve, i.e. why you need to know the number of lines?

Comment: Thank you for your good response.
When I test it, there is no value in powershell_ise.
I wanted to create a function corresponding to "more" when I needed page splitting in powershell_ise.
Now that I know the maximum number of rows in powershell.exe, I think it will help me if I apply it well.

Comment: OK, note that even the built-in `more` does not work in ISE. Probably for the very reason that the necessary information is not available there.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality I really need is `git status`, `git diff` in powershell_ise with highlight and output paging.
It seems that the current version of powershell_ise does not solve the problem itself.

Although not completely satisfactory, I have devised a practical solution and created the following function.

## source code

```
function hhd-git-diff
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
    )

    $res = git diff
    hhd-git-colored-output -INPUT_OBJECT $res
}



function hhd-git-status
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
    )

    $res = git status
    hhd-git-colored-output -INPUT_OBJECT $res
}



function hhd-git-colored-output
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
        [System.Object]
        $INPUT_OBJECT
    )



    $lineNum = 1



    $INPUT_OBJECT | 
    Out-String | 
    foreach {

        $_ -split "\n" |

        foreach {

            if($lineNum % [Console]::WindowHeight -eq 0)
            {
                Read-Host "continue? press any key..."
            }

            $lineNum++

            if($_ -like "diff --git *")
            {
                Write-Host ""
                Write-Host ""
                Write-Host ""
                Write-Host ("#"*80) -ForegroundColor Cyan
                Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Cyan
                Write-Host ("#"*80) -ForegroundColor Cyan
                Read-Host "continue? press any key..."
                $lineNum = 1
            }
            elseif($_ -like "--- *")
            {
            }
            elseif($_ -like "+++ *")
            {
            }
            elseif($_ -like "-*")
            {
                Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red
            }
            elseif($_ -like "+*")
            {
                Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Green
            }
            elseif($_ -like "On branch *")
            {
                Write-Host ("#"*80) -ForegroundColor Cyan
                Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Cyan
            }
            elseif($_ -like "Your branch is*")
            {
                Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Cyan
                Write-Host ("#"*80) -ForegroundColor Cyan
            }
            elseif($_ -like "Changes to be committed:*")
            {
                Write-Host ("-"*80) -ForegroundColor Green
                Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Green
            }
            elseif($_ -like "Changes not staged for commit:*")
            {
                Write-Host ("-"*80) -ForegroundColor Red
                Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red
            }
            elseif($_ -like "Untracked files:*")
            {
                Write-Host ("-"*80) -ForegroundColor Black
                Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Black
            }
            elseif($_ -like "*modified:*")
            {
                Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Yellow
            }
            elseif($_ -like "*deleted:*")
            {
                Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Gray
            }
        }
    }



}
```

## screen shot

[image]

[image]